# Is there a way to make this SQL more efficient?

Tags: sql, database, performance

Consider the following tables:

### department

```
deptid      (type:INT)
deptname    (type: TEXT)
hours       (type:INT)
active      (type:BIT)
```

### employee

```
empid       (type:INT)
empname     (type: TEXT)
deptid      (type: INT)
designation (type: TEXT)
salary      (type: INT)
```

Write a query to return the columns empname and deptname of the employees belonging to those
departments that have a head count of 4 or more. The records should be returned in alphabetical order of empname

This was my take:

```
SELECT e1.empname, d.deptname from employee AS e1
FULL JOIN department AS d on e1.deptid = d.deptid
  WHERE e1.deptid IN(
    SELECT deptid FROM(
      SELECT e2.deptid, COUNT(e2.empid)
      FROM employee AS e2
      GROUP BY e2.deptid
      HAVING COUNT(e2.empid) >= 4
    )
  )
ORDER BY empname;
```

How would you improve on this?

Comment: No, not left join. INNER since you want exact matches (where dept is already known to have 4 or more employees)

Comment: many DBMS don't allow the keyword `AS` for the table alias. Should it not be `table t1` instead of `table AS t1`

Comment: Anything that's SQL-92 compatible. Eg HSQL with SquirrelSQL to test code in..

Comment: I think I'm correct with the LEFT JOIN. See. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp quote: "Return all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table". Since Employee is the driver... I'd assume you'd still want to Employees where the department wasn't present...

Comment: @JGFMK - that conclusion is wrong. You specifically want `employees belonging to those departments that have a head count of 4 or more.`  So LEFT/FULL JOIN will give you ALL employees, whether or not they fit the criteria

Comment: The main problem is not with JOINS but the fact that an `IN clause` is in some DBMS optimized as a element-by-element lookup/filter, whereas turning that to a JOIN makes use of hash matches or join mechanics.

Comment: So are joins generally considered faster than IN clauses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is shorter and probably performs faster too

```
SELECT e1.empname, d.deptname
from (
      SELECT e2.deptid
      FROM employee AS e2
      GROUP BY e2.deptid
      HAVING COUNT(e2.empid) >= 4
    ) G
inner join employee AS e1 on e1.deptid = G.deptid
INNER JOIN department AS d on d.deptid = G.deptid
ORDER BY e1.empname;
```

Start with the grouping. You don't need COUNT from the inner query.
Then, join to both tables just to get the names.

**INNER JOIN** is used because once the count is complete, we already know that

1. the employees exist
2. the department exists

Comment: I like your answer. But if there was a data integrity error where an Employee record pointed to a department that didn't exists, those employees wouldn't show up. I guess you'd just change the second join to a left join to make that fly & end up with a blank department name.

Comment: @JGFMK You need to restate your question then. See my comment under the question.

Comment: +1 well explained. (was confused by keyword 'AS' which is not allowed here for Oracle but it's fine e.g. for MySQL or HSQL)

Comment: I guess this may be me then. My interpretation of Department was based on deptid's in the Employee record. The question does say Departments. My bad!

Comment: @JGFMK - In case you mean 4 employees can have the same deptid that doesn't exist in department.deptid, then yes, LEFT JOIN the last part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, it will work properly.

```
select empname,deptname from employee,department
where 
employee.deptid=department.deptid and employee.deptid
in
(
  select deptId from employee group by deptid having count(*)>=4
) 
order by empname
```