# My SQL query is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make this SQL more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021993/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-sql-more-efficient)

Consider the following tables:

- `department`:

  ```
  deptid (type: INT)
  deptname (type: TEXT)
  hours (type: INT)
  active (type: BIT)
  ```
- `employee`:

  ```
  empid (type: INT)
  empname (type: TEXT)
  deptid (type: INT)
  designation (type: TEXT)
  salary (type: INT)
  ```

Write a query to return the columns `empname` and `deptname` of the employees belonging to those departments that have a head count of 4 or more. The records should be returned in alphabetical order of `empname`.

My solution is as below.

```
SELECT e.empname,d.deptname
FROM employee e,department d
WHERE e.deptid=d.deptid
      AND d.deptid
         IN
(
SELECT deptid
FROM employee
GROUP BY deptid
HAVING COUNT(*)>=4
)
ORDER BY e.empname;
```

Comment: This is probably homework.  I found the exact same question at [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1127784-391-1.aspx).

Comment: @Venk You really should check out the link that I provided.  It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found on [this link](http://www.php.de/datenbanken/76685-erledigt-problem-mit-having-count.html).

```
SELECT employee.empname, department.deptname
FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.deptid = department.deptid
WHERE employee.deptid IN 
(
  SELECT employee.deptid
  FROM employee
  GROUP BY employee.deptid
  HAVING COUNT(employee.deptid) >= 4
)
ORDER BY employee.empname ASC;
```

**Edit**:  If you would like me to explain anything in this solution, please don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: @Venk Just a follow-up question; did this help you out or is this not the answer you were looking for?